# request to server every minute - other way then timeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to fetch data from server every minute to check for a new data. For now I am doing that in a loop with Timeout but I think there might be a better way to do that. How should that be done?

```
async componentDidMount () {
    await this.callApi();
    await this.callNames();
}

callApi = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('/rates');
        if (response.status === 200) {
            const body = await response.json();
            this.setState({ rates: body.rates, ratesError: null });
        } else {
            this.setState({ ratesError: 'Error getting currency rates' });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({ ratesError: err });
    }
    setTimeout(this.callApi, 60000);
}
```

Comment: setTimeout is the way most people would do it. Only other way would be to look into websockets instead of Ajax calls.

Comment: I've got a problem with Travis build I thought it might be a cause. But if that is standard way maybe it isn't that then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610764/travis-build-pass-but-looped-in-app-js

Comment: `setTimeout(this.callApi.bind(this), 60000);`

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately that doesn't change anything in terms of Travis build...

Answer (score 6):

You could use `setInterval`

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(this.callApi, 60000);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score -1):

You can use firebase or firestore as your server, it will automatically reload your data as it is updated. it also provide more functionalities as well.
check the other features from link below.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/